# Calculating preferred height based on actual Codenameone's component width

Tags: java, codenameone

I'm creating a custom Codenameone component that has variable size. The component displays a fixed amount of text, spanning multiple lines. Thus the width and height are related. If the width is small less text fits on a line and more lines are needed. I've managed to set preferred width and preferred height. The trouble is that when the actual painting occurs the width is apparently given by the graphics object `graphics.getClipWidth()` and doesn't match my preferred width. Thus my preferred height (which appears equal to `graphics.getClipHeight()` when painting) is incorrect as the clip width is unequal to my preferred width, which was used to calculate the preferred height. How can I get `graphics.getClipHeight()` to have the correct height? In other words, is it possible to specify the height of the component using the width the component will actually have when rendering?

Best wishes
Marc K

Answer (score 0):

That's the exact problem we have with the `TextArea` and I'm afraid there are no easy answers. E.g. if the component provides a preferred size of X the layout manager might decide to allocate size differently thus requiring a different layout.

This was a conscious design choice we made when building Codename One, in order to accomplish this you will need to "reflow" effectively recursing thru the hierarchy recalculating sizes/dimensions until you get the best fit. These algorithms are by definition slow and harder to benchmark (since its hard to predict how reflow will behave on the device with varying fonts, paddings etc.).

In the `TextArea` we have a "poor mans reflow" that triggers revalidation if the width doesn't seem right. This has been a source of many problems in `TextArea`.

You can see this in the [TextArea source](https://github.com/codenameone/CodenameOne/blob/master/CodenameOne/src/com/codename1/ui/TextArea.java), search for the `setShouldCalcPreferredSize` calls.

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply. Would making `getPreferredH()` return different values depending on whether or not `getWidth()` is set (i.e. returns a value unequal to 0) work? It seems to work in a BoxLayout-Y. Alternative would be using the screen's width to estimate the height - that sounds fragile.

Comment: That wouldn't be the right way to work. You should generally override calcPreferredSize() and in that case it should return the different value.

Comment: Ok i'll try that then.